# Why would USB ports that work using a live Cd not work on an install of Ubuntu 13.10 on a Dell 15R?

Tags: 13.04, usb, mouse

I installed the Ubuntu 13.10 in my Dell Inspiron 15R. Everything worked fine while using a Live CD but once Ubuntu was installed the USB ports didn't work with several devices. What steps can I take to find out why, or to get the devices working?

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e004 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:648d Microdia Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**EDIT:** updated the output of `lsusb`

Comment: Is it possible to look at the last half of the main sentence and make it a little clearer.  I'm not positive what you are asking.  Thanks

Comment: Sorry.

I installed the Ubuntu 13.10 in the Notebook Dell Inspiron 15R and the ports USB not worked.
I plug pendrive, mouse wireless and not worked.

I tried on live cd and worked perfectly.

It's now clear?

Comment: I edited the original question to reflect your comment.  If it is approved make sure it is correct (and if necessary edit it yourself) This will also bump it up which hopefully will help. Sorry I don't have an actual answer.

Comment: After the install, did you apply all available updates?

Comment: I already applied all the updates.

Comment: what is your pendrive brand?? plug it in to your computer, open up a terminal (ALT + CTRL + T will do) & type `lsusb`, then post the output to see whether system detects a usb input. :)

Comment: Did you try this by inserting a USB flash drive?? if so, what was it you inserted??

Comment: I insert a pendrive 16GB and a mouse wireless Dell. I tried all USB ports.

Comment: Did you also check your BIOS for any USB hardware or EHCI related settings. And If my guess was right, it should be with the installation package. Because, mostly on-board USB's should work with no errors.

Comment: I dont know to see this. The USB ports on Windows 8 worked.